# How to give a div or IMG a 'minimum size'

Tags: css, image, user-interface, zooming

I have these two images that are 50px by 50px.  They're each locked in 50px-by-50px divs.  I don't want them to shrink when a user uses full-page zooming to reduce the page size.  Actually, I want the images to be zoomed, by default, to about 75px by 75px, and I want them to shrink to a minimum of 50px.

Can anyone tell me how to do this?  Can I somehow stretch the images to take up 100% of the div and then just make the div 75px by default?  Then, can I somehow set a minimum of 50px for the div?  Can you please show me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set `min-width` and `min-height` style properties on the *div* tag and set the *img* tag to span the full width and height of the *div* tag.

Comment: So, what's wrong with this code: `.button_inside_border.img{
  span=100%;
}`.  Also, sick name, @Siva.

Comment: Also it's `.target_class img{}`.  Note the space and the rubbed period.  `/s/./ /`?  Whatever.